# Blank space instead cyrillic letters after compiling to dvi

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I've got a weird problem with fonts, I believe.

On my home PC I compile a TEX-file (texifying to DVI) just fine, on my work PC I've got blank spaces in places where monotype font is used; on another work PC the whole text is with blank spaces, so that I just see some numbers, math and latin characters.

I believe that that's the problem with fonts, but I can't figure out where to look for the source of the problem, as the source and all the settings are the same.

The MWE is below, along with screenshots (good and bad).

Using MikTEX v.2.9. 32-bit system on Windows 7, 10.

Thanks

```
    \documentclass[10pt,paper=a5,pagesize=auto,twoside=semi,open=any,headings=small,headings=optiontohead,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{nimbusmononarrow}
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{%
\fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
\fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
\fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
\fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
\hyphenchar\font=`\-% to allow hyphenation
}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[unicode, linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\begin{document}
Эффект направленности группы рассматривается в этих записках только по отношению к полезному отражённому сигналу. Возможное уменьшение теоретического отношения в реальных съёмках, в целом, известно: <<\texttt{{\itshape ослабляя регулярные волны\footnote{имеются в виду регулярные волны-помехи}, интерференционная система увеличивает отношение сигнал/помеха в $N$ раз}. \ul{Такова теоретическая оценка}, получаемая \ul{для идеальных условий} суммирования упругих колебаний. \ul{Однако в реальных условиях} (неровный рельеф местности, неоднородности ЗМС, флуктуации кинематических и динамических параметров полезных и мешающих волн) \ul{эффект направленности группы приёмников может снижаться в 1.5-2 раза и более}, что необходимо учитывать}>> [\citen{6}, с.523]. Ослабление регулярных помех, отношения их амплитуд к амплитудам полезного сигнала не обсуждаются, т.к. этим вопросам посвящена огромная литература. Далее рассматривается только статистический эффект группирования. О третьем эффекте -- осреднений условий установки
\end{document}
```

[image: the ok compilation]
[image: the problematic compilation]

Comment: Which distributions do you have?

Comment: MikTEX v.2.9. 32-bit system

Comment: I suspect you should run as administrator (from the command line) `updmap.exe` to refresh the type1 fonts database.

Comment: Bernard, it didn't help. I used to press the "Update" button from the Settings GUI, now I did that from command line. Nothing changed.

Comment: Is the monotype font installed? I have no problem on my MiKTeX.

Comment: well, the "Install missing packages on the fly" option is checked, so the fonts were downloaded and installed by MikTEX while first-time compiling. Any way to check that?

Comment: Use MiKTeX Package manager: it will display the list of all available packages, mentioning if it is installed (and when it was).

Comment: all ok there. "nimbus15" installed when the file was compiled for the first time.

Comment: The only point should `updmap.exe` You can check if the mono font is mentioned in `psfonts.map` (it a simple  text file that you may read, but never write it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seemed to be in the configuration  files of some of WinEdt / MikTEX / Yap.

I completely removed and reinstalled MikTEX (running setup with admin rights just in case), and rebuilt the WinEdt configuration files (Options - Maintenance - Rebuild all), that solved the problem.